# Why is my selection sort sorting the array out of order?

Tags: java, sorting

This is part of my program:

```
private static int[] array = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 7, 8, 6, 10, 9};

private static void selectionSort(int arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) 
    {
        int index = i; 
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[index])
            {
                index = j;
            }

            int smallerNumber = arr[index]; 
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = smallerNumber;
        }   
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to sort all of the numbers in order. It is printing the following:

```
1 3 2 5 4 6 7 8 9 10
```

I don't understand why some numbers are in order, and others aren't. Can anyone be of assistance?

Comment: Please move the last `for` statement outside the first to make this compile as you probably intended. Then, what did you find out while running your code in a debugger step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be comparing `arr[j]` with `arr[index]` (not `arr[i]`) and you shouldn't swap the elements until your inner loop completes. And you can use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) to print your array. Something like,

```
private static void selectionSort(int arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        int index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[index]) {
                index = j;
            }
        }
        if (index != i) {
            int smallerNumber = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = smallerNumber;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 7, 8, 6, 10, 9 };
    selectionSort(array);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Output is (as expected)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

think this is bad

```
        if (arr[j] < arr[index])
```

that should be

```
        if (arr[j] < arr[i])
```

because you always move the smallest one to the current position of i.

or if you want to optimize, do the swap at the end like Elliot suggests.

Not working, you cannot just swap every time, only if the number is smaller, so move the swap inside the if. You can also get rid of index, it is useless unless you want to swap at the end only.

```
    if (arr[j] < arr[i])
    {
        int smallerNumber = arr[j]; 
        arr[j] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = smallerNumber;
    }
```